# I can't create database normally in cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

When I create a new tenant and wanna create a database, the database get a same name with other database in another tenant. Then it will report error.

[image]

Comment: Try not to use pictures, sometimes the picture can not be displayed, you can display the operation process in markdown format

Answer (score 1):

Because cluster_schema is an internal system database, users are not allowed to create a database with this name